# How to add number into name attribute of html element in razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to add number into name attribute of html element in razor.

```
 @for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfTravelers; j++)
    {
<input type="text" name="FirstNameEN@j"  class="input-text full-width" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
}
```

In this case razor can not detect j number.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@()` as shown :-

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfTravelers; j++)
 {
    <input type="text" name="FirstNameEN@(j)" class="input-text full-width" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfTravelers; j++)
{
     <input type="text" name='@("FirstNameEN"+j)' class="input-text full-width" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
}
```